# declare a variable using `execute` Interpolation in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I want to declare a a sub-string of a variable to another variable. I tested taking a sub-string using terraform console.

```
> echo 'element(split (".", "10.250.3.0/24"), 2)' | terraform console
> 3
```

my subnet is 10.250.3.0/24 and I want my virtual machine to get private IP address within this subnet mask 10.250.3.6. I want this to get automatically assign by looking at subnet address. What I've tried;

test.tf

```
variable subnet {
  type = "string"
  default = "10.250.3.0/24"
  description = "subnet mask myTestVM will live"
}

variable myTestVM_subnet {
  type = "string"
  default = "10.250." ${element(split(".", var.trusted_zone_onpremises_subnet), 2)} ".6"
}
```

And then I test it by

```
terraform console
>Failed to load root config module: Error parsing /home/anum/test/test.tf: At 9:25: illegal char
```

I guess its just simple syntax issue. but couldn't figure out what!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you've seen, you can't interpolate the values of variables in Terraform.

You can, however, interpolate [locals](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/locals.html) instead and use those if you want to avoid repeating yourself anywhere.

So you could do something like this:

```
variable "subnet" {
  type = "string"
  default = "10.250.3.0/24"
  description = "subnet mask myTestVM will live"
}

locals {
  myTestVM_subnet = "10.250.${element(split(".", var.trusted_zone_onpremises_subnet), 2)}.6"
}

resource "aws_instance" "instance" {
  ...
  private_ip = "${local.myTestVM_subnet}"
}
```

Where the `aws_instance` is just for demonstration and could be any resource that requires/takes an IP address.

As a better option in this specific use case though you could use the [`cidrhost`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#cidrhost-iprange-hostnum-) function to generate the host address in a given subnet.

So in your case you would instead have something like this:

```
resource "aws_instance" "instance" {
  ...
  private_ip = "${cidrhost(var.subnet, 6)}"
}
```

Which would create an AWS instance with a private IP address of `10.250.3.6`. This can then make it much easier to create a whole series of machines that increment the IP address used by using the `count` meta parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Terraform doesn't allows interpolations declaration of variables in `default`. So I get ;

```
Error: variable "myTestVM_subnet": default may not contain interpolations
```

and the syntax error really got fixed after banging my head, so here is what Terraform likes;

```
private_ip_address = "10.250.${element(split(".", "${var.subnet}"), 2)}.5"
```