# How to pass down file path to module?

Tags: terraform

I am learning terraform modules.

I've created module for Google Provider.

```
provider "google" {
  credentials = "${var.credentials}"
  project     = "${var.project_id}"
  region      = "${var.region}"
  zone        = "${var.zone}"
}
```

I want to pass credential file path form the module consuming above.

Here is the consumer module.

**main.tf**

```
module "google" {
  source      = "../modules/google-provider"
  project_id = "${var.project_id}"
  credentials = "${var.credentials}"
}
```

**variables.tf**

```
variable "credentials" {
    default = "${file("cred.json")}"
}
```

This is the error I am getting:

`Error: variable "credentials": default may not contain interpolations`

I read this stackoverflow [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49740019/9958058) but did not understand how it will work.

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: What don't you understand about the linked answer?

Comment: I did not understand where I should define locals - in consumer module or main module (Google provider). I tried to define that in consumer module and pass that down but it was giving me same error.

Answer (score 3):

from the docs,

> When you declare variables in the root module of your configuration,
>   you can set their values using CLI options and environment variables.
>   When you declare them in child modules, the calling module should pass
>   values in the module block.

In your case,

```
#This is your calling module, hence you need to pass variables to child module from here
module "google" {
  source      = "../modules/google-provider"
  passed_project_id_to_child = "${var.project_id}"
  passed_credentials_to_child = "${var.credentials}"
}
```

UPDATE: for some reasons, terraform is not allowing you to read file with interpolation syntax create a data source of type **local_file** [docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/local/d/file.html#content_base64)

```
data "local_file" "credJSON" {
    filename = "./cred.json"
}
```

then you will need to do something like this in your module's configuration file or you can also create a seperate file for that too,

```
variable passed_project_id_to_child{
  default = "${jsonencode(data.credJSON.content).projectId}"
}
variable passed_credentials_to_child{}

provider "google" {
      credentials = "${var.passed_project_id_to_child}"
      project     = "${var.passed_project_id_to_child}"
      region      = "${var.region}"
      zone        = "${var.zone}"
    }
```

Hopefully this works.
Read more [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/modules.html#calling-a-child-module)

Comment: thank you for the answer and the link to the doc. However, I am having trouble passing file content down to module. I think, my question must rephrase to "How to access file content in module?" as I am getting error saying `variable "credentials": default may not contain interpolations`. Please let me know if I'm following wrong path.

Comment: Thank you @Claxx for the edit. I will read the docs you mentioned and give it a try.